# SO_REUSEADDR with UDP datagrams - Resource unavailable

Tags: sockets, unix, udp

I'm using SO_REUSEADDR option, but I'm not sure why am getting
Resource temporary unvailable option.

I'm testing client server code on 127.0.0.1

```
if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 )
{
    perror("socket() error!!\n");
    exit(1);
}

if ( setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse) ) < 0 ) {
    perror("SO_REUSEADDR failed::");
    exit(1);
}

while(1) {

    nbytes_read = recvfrom(sockfd, (void *)&recvd_msg, sizeof(recvd_msg),
                           flags, &from, &from_len);
    printf("nbytes_read = %d\n", nbytes_read);
    if(nbytes_read == -1) {
        perror("client: recvfrom() failed");
        return FAILED;
    }
    if (nbytes_read > 0) {
        if(recvd_msg.hdr.msgtype == DATA)
            printf("recvd %d bytes from server\n", recvd_msg.hdr.payload_size);
            ftp_show_payload(&recvd_msg);
    }
    if(recvd_msg.hdr.is_last == TRUE) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Error message:
"    client: recvfrom() failed: Resource temporarily unavailable"

errno:11

After trying to run client for 3-4 times, I get the data, I'm not sure whats happening.

**Also, this problem is on Ubuntu Linux, but when I run the same client server on Solaris,
it works fine!!**

Comment: You don't need the label or the goto. Use continue. And you can only get zero in non-blocking mode, in which case you should select(), not just spin. And you don't need 'else' after 'return'.

Comment: ok, I've changed all that you said, but still I'm not sure why I get EAGAIN(Resource unavailable)..

Comment: No you haven't. If you're getting EAGAIN you must be in non-blocking mode, so you need to call select() to tell you when data is available.

Comment: To be in non-blocking mode, i think we need to set O_NONBLOCK, but in my code, I'm not doing that

Comment: OK, so have you removed the pointless SO_REUSEADDR yet?

Answer (score 1):

`SO_REUSEADDR` is useful when you use `bind()`, but here you are not using bind.

I dont see any problem if `recvfrom()` returns `-1`

Use `bind()` and replace your call `recvfrom()` with `recv()`. `recv()` will receive all the packets at the port you used in your bind call.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your test is invalid. recvfrom() can return zero, which doesn't indicate an error. It is only valid to call perror() if you get -1. So you may not have a problem at all ..
2. I don't see why you're using SO_REUSEADDR at all here, as you're not binding to a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trimming out any other socket configuration?  EAGAIN is typically returned when you read a non-blocking socket and there's no data available.  The manpage for recvfrom lists the possible errnos that will be set on failure with an explanation for each one.

Comment: i get errno:11 Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: That's the "pretty" name for EAGAIN (aka EWOULDBLOCK).  You can verify that by printing out `strerror(EAGAIN)`.  Sadly I also know offhand that 11 is EAGAIN as well...

Comment: but why will I get EAGAIN, my udp file server, sends me lot of data, and sometimes I see it, and sometimes I see EAGAIN, what could be the reason

Comment: Data won't be available as often as you can call recvfrom(). You need select(). See above. Or else just use blocking mode.